# Is it possible to change xib files around?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xib

I am working in xcode4 and I have done a bunch of work on the viewcontroller's xib file, but I'd like to link that view to a different set of .h and .m files, so my question is if its possible to change what links a xib file to its .h and .m?

Thanks!

```
@interface TGTViewController : UIViewController{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my question is if its possible to change what links a xib file to its .h and .m?

**Yes.**

First, realize that a .xib file is really just an archive of serialized objects, so usually contains more than one object.

Second, know that the object that's the *file's owner* (often a view controller) isn't even contained in the .xib -- it's the object that loads the .xib.

Third, you can look at (and change) the type of an object in the identity inspector in the .xib editor (a.k.a Interface Builder).

So, if you want to change the type of an object that's stored *in* the .xib file, such as a custom view, you can simply select the object in IB, go to the identity inspector, and change the type. If you want to change the type of an object that's loading the .xib file, such as a view controller, then select the *file's owner* icon in the .xib and change the type. You'll also need to change the type used to create the object in your code, of course.

There's nothing that links a .xib file to a .m or .h file. If the .xib contains objects of a given type, the .xib loading mechanism will expect to find a class definition for that type and will throw an exception if it doesn't find it, but it doesn't care what the source files are named.

Comment: Oh ok I think I know what your talking about, is this the code the loading mechanism? see the code I just added

Comment: It is from my .h file

Comment: No, that's the class declaration. .xib loading happens when you load a .xib file, either by hand using `NSNib` or by initializing an object such as a view controller using a .xib file.